# UFW blocks Docker interfaces when default outgoing policy is 'deny'

Tags: docker, connection, ufw

Given that I configured UFW like so

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default deny outgoing
```

and just allowed certain ports for outgoing and incoming connections. It works fine, except when   connecting between different interfaces on the same machine, eg. interface created for Docker's bridged network. (I didn't actually check any other interfaces yet).

For example I have a Docker container

```
docker run --network some-net -p 127.0.0.1:50100:80 image-name
```

Now I can't establish a connection to the container, as it times out with the message:

```
$ curl localhost:50100
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I can unlock the connection by either changing my outgoing policy to `allow`, or by adding a rule to allow **output** connections from a specific interface:

```
ufw allow out on br-03a38c6b9c51
```

UFW configuration is as follows:

```
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="DROP"
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="DROP"
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
DEFAULT_APPLICATION_POLICY="SKIP"
```

I already tried to add `--iptables=false` to Docker options in order to eliminate that it is the case with of rules Dockers creates when initializing a network.
No problem with the calling any external hosts from container once it has its port opened in UFW rules.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at these questions here:

1. [Ubuntu ufw: set a rule on a per interface basis](https://serverfault.com/questions/270715/ubuntu-ufw-set-a-rule-on-a-per-interface-basis)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/703896/forward-only-web-traffic-to-another-interface

ufw applies the rule to all interfaces by default. So have to specify which rule applies to which interface.

I think the questions in the links will better explain this.