# Why isn't logic working on ufw?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

Let's say I want to allow my own external IP in on tun0 interface port 443.

Why doesn't

```
sudo ufw allow from 217.xxx.xxx.xxx proto tcp to tun0 port 443
```

Work (not on tun0 either) when

```
sudo ufw allow from 217.xxx.xxx.xxx proto tcp to any port 443
```

works?

All other answers (on this site) are allowing any, I don't want that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu ufw: set a rule on a per interface basis](https://serverfault.com/questions/270715/ubuntu-ufw-set-a-rule-on-a-per-interface-basis)

Comment: @djdomi not actually, at least so I understand it. I want to open port **443** on network **interface tun0** for **one ip address**  only. isn't that opening for everybody? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify **any** or an **ip-address** before the command **port**

if you want just one address:

**sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to** (your tun0 ip address) **111.111.111.111 port 443 from** (the ip you want to allow in) **222.222.222.222**

**`sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to 111.111.111.111 port 443 from 222.222.222.222`**

If you want to allow everyone:

```
sudo ufw allow in on tun0 to any port 443
```

Answer (score 0):

because the parameter for `to` is an IP address, not an interface. To specify an interface you need to use `on tun0`. See [man ufw](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html)

Comment: I've tested to replace to (to) on, (as I wrote in my question), and that doesn't work.