# How can I deny a specific port on a certain interface/public IP using ufw?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I tried using the command below but I can still connect to it via browser.

```
sudo ufw deny from any to {public IP} port 8080
```

I am running a wikijs (running on port 8080) on a server with cloudflare tunnel access. I want to block browser access when they try to browse for http://public-ip:8080

Comment: check this one https://serverfault.com/questions/270715/ubuntu-ufw-set-a-rule-on-a-per-interface-basis if that help.

Comment: that link pertains to allowing a rule on a network interface. a bit opposite of what im trying to do.